# Multidimensional Array Not Updating (or is it...?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, dom

I have the most peculiar issue I can't seem to solve without writing band-aid code.

**FULL SOURCE:**
http://sinsysonline.com/tictactoe_test.html
**or Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/JsXEP/

I am using a `multidimensional array` for the **JS** and a `table` for the **HTML** for data and display purposes.

So, our data will look something like this for **JS**:

`var b = [ ["","",""], ["","",""], ["","",""] ];`

The table will be a standard table with some **CSS** tweaks for our **HTML**:

```
<table id="board">
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

So, here is the problem. The input works just fine, resetting the game *appears* to work fine, but let's make a `use-case` so I can demonstrate the problem.

If I utilize a `grid size` of `3` initially, then try to make a game with a `grid size` of `4` without refreshing the page, the data seems to display at the top right for my `array` that the code is working as intended.

However, when you `console.log(b)`, it never actually updates `b` and anything after the first `three rows` in the table don't respond.

**I'm given a console error of:**

`TypeError: b[row] is undefined`

Why isn't `b` actually updating with the increased value, even though I define it as `var b=[];` at the beginning of my `click-handler` for `#go`?

And why is my `#alert` box for debugging filling in the correct `b` value?

**Scratches Head**

Any help is appreciated...

---

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dashboard">
    <p>How large is your grid? (3-10)</p>
    <input type="text" id="size" size="1" />

    <p>Which icon would you like?</p>
    <select name="mydropdown" id="mark">
        <option value="check">Check-Mark</option>
        <option value="x">Traditonal X</option>
        <option value="o">Traditional O</option>
    </select>
    <h3 id="title">Troubleshooting Console</h3>
    <input type="button" id="go" value="Create Board / Reset" />
    <p id="alert">Alerts Live Here</p> 
</div>
<table id="board">
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#go").click(function () {
    var b=[],
        s = parseInt($("#size").val()),
        v = $("#mark").val();
    if (s<3 || s>10) { alert("That is not a valid input. Please select 3-10"); return; }
    $('#board tr').remove();
    $('#alert').text("Your Turn!");

    for (var i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        var t = [];
        var $tr = $('<tr />').data('index', i + 1);

        for (var j = 0; j < s; j++) {
            t[j] = "";
            $('<td />').data('index', j + 1).appendTo($tr);
        }
        b.push(t);
        $("#board").append($tr);
    }

    $("#board").on('click', 'td', function () {
        var $td = $(this),
            td = $td.data('index')-1,
            row = $td.parent().data('index')-1;
        b[row][td] = "X";
        $td.removeClass().addClass(v);
        $('#alert').text(b);
    });
});
```

**FULL SOURCE:**
http://sinsysonline.com/tictactoe_test.html
**or Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/JsXEP/

Comment: Did you check the value of `row`? And jsfiddle would have been better to debug.

Comment: Added fiddle. And yes, I did. It returns 3 (on the 4th row, which is what we would EXPECT to see). The problem appears to be somewhere within the definition of `b`.

Comment: On another note, if I just create the `array` itself with a `loop up to 10`, _it works fine indefinitely_... but that doesn't serve my purpose, as I want the `array` to be directly proportional to the `table`. Or if I **start** with 10 for my value, then all subsequent variations work as well. It's only when selecting a lower value initially than the next `game`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of the closure property and multiple definitions of on click function. [`Updated Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/JsXEP/1/)

```
$("#board").on('click', 'td', function () {
    var $td = $(this),
        td = $td.data('index')-1,
        row = $td.parent().data('index')-1;
    b[row][td] = "X";
    $td.removeClass().addClass(v);
    $('#alert').text(b);
});
```

This function is registered every time user changes the settings and whenever it is defined, it captures the `b`. So, first time, lets say, `b` is [3][3] and the on click function is created with that. Next time, `b` is [4][4] and a new on click function is created (old one still exists, with `b` [3][3]). So both of them are fired now onwards. If I select anything outside 3 x 3, the old one fails. That's why you are facing this problem.

So, I just moved the definition of on click function, `b` and `v` outside and it works fine now.

Comment: *Laughing* I tried making them global, but forgot to separate the click function :-P Thank you so much!

Comment: Now just some algorithm on the array logic. Thank you again so much. I'm relatively new to DOM manipulation, and its a juggle to switch from Javascript to jQuery, but people like you make it possible :-) [View Current Version](http://sinsysonline.com/tictactoe_test.html)